# Menu/Picture Preview NA, Automatic Focus not working

Tags: autofocus, sensor, display

I have a Canon Rebel XSI. It is from 2008. Original everything except lense. I cannot get the menu option to display in any mode, pushing the button does nothing. I cannot get any pictures I recently took to come up in the display, and again, pushing the button does nothing. I have recently cleaned the camera in an attempt to get the sensors to work. Automatic focus on the lense is not working either...

I am currently at the beach, and typically use the picture preview to adjust my settings to know how I am doing as I am shooting, and of course rely on automatic focus as I don't trust my wacky eyes to be making manual adjustments.

Anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: What _does_ work? You say you recently cleaned the camera to get the sensors to work -- do you mean that something other than the things you describe now was broken before?

Comment: No.  Cleaning did not seem to do anything, and I thought it might have been a sensor issue.  The camera does take pictures in any mode, and I can use manual focus.  

I cannot access the menu, I cannot get automatic focus on the lense to work and I cannot get the picture preview function to work.

Comment: Are the pictures you take apparently fine when you examine them on a computer? Does the rear LCD work otherwise?

Comment: Did this start on the beach? Might you have gotten sand or water in the camera?

Comment: Pictures are fine, and the SD card also seems fine.  Issues did not start at the beach, and camera seems dry and no sand found inside anywhere.  LCD works otherwise, and reacts appropriately to sensor when something is in front of the eye viewer.

Comment: So the only two things that don't work are the playback button and autofocus? Do you have another lens you can test?

Comment: I do, I did, and still have all 3 of the same issues:
- Can't access my menu at all, such as to format an SD card
- Can't access the playback
- Auto focus doesn't work

Comment: UPDATE: The Motherboard is dying, which after 10 years with this camera is devastating.  If anyone is aware of where to find one for a Canon EOS XSI Rebel, I would love to know

Comment: As much as you love that camera, I would suggest looking for a newer model rather than a replacement motherboard. A lot had changed in a positive way in the last decade, and I bet you will grow to love a new one too.

Comment: I plan on upgrading in addition to searching for the Motherboard replacement.  Thanks!

Comment: Good luck! I bet, though, once you have the upgrade, you won't look back.